# Facebook leads ad missing fields

Tags: facebook, ads, lead

I am developing an App in Node.js for Lead Ad retrieval. Everything is working fine except, we recently realised that in the field_data we are missing some fields which are on Lead Add Form.
The user data fields are on the first page of the form, and the consent tick boxes are on the second page of the form. And exactly the consent tick boxes are not present when we retrieve the leads. Any ideas what might be missing in form configuration or something else?

Answer (score 0):

After few months of accepting the issue we filled the ticket with FB and got response which solves the issue - our Ad contained check boxes as disclaimers which are not part of the field_data object:

Reading Custom Disclaimer Responses

The field_data does not contain the responses to optional custom disclaimer check boxes that the user would have filled out. To retrieve the responses, use the custom_disclaimer_responses field.

```
curl -X GET \
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<LEADGEN_ID>?
fields=custom_disclaimer_responses"
```

Response:

```
{
  "custom_disclaimer_responses": [
    {
      "checkbox_key": "optional_1",
      "is_checked": "1"
    },
    {
      "checkbox_key": "optional_2",
      "is_checked": ""
    }
  ],
  "id": "1231231231"
}
```